# Converting input to int gives an incorrect number

Tags: c#

With the code below, when I write what the input is to the console, it returns `54` if I enter `6`. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I would like to know.

```
namespace VariablePractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World.");
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + input);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Int32.Parse rather than using Convert.ToInt32. Convert.ToInt32(string s) method converts the specified string representation of 32-bit signed integer equivalent. Int32.Parse (string s) method converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent.  So, therefore change your code to this:        int input;
Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);

Comment: As you can see from the duplicates (just a handful of the many similar questions already on Stack Overflow), you're not the first to fail to understand that the `char` type represents a _character code point_ and not an actual numeric value. Passing it to `Convert.ToInt32()` gives you the character code point value, not the numeric value that digit would represent.